# Experiencing an issue with the tilde (Bitwise NOT) operator

Tags: c

I've been experimenting with bitwise operators, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0b110000;
    int y = ~x;
    printf("x: %d", x);
    printf("\ny: %d", y);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code block is:

```
x: 48
y: -49
```

The thing I don't understand is why `y=-49`, because I used the bitwise NOT operator, shouldn't it reverse the bits and make `y=0b001111` (`y=15`)?

I tried to use other numbers to check if it was an exception, it was not. I tried every number from 0 to 29 and the pattern of `y = -(x+1)` remained.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `make y=0b001111` - no, `x` is `0b00000000000000000000000000110000`.

Comment: now try the same with `unsigned int` (or std::uint8_t). And how can you use printf when you include iostream? Shouldn't you be using std::cout? (we like compiling minimal reproducable examples here)

Comment: @PepijnKramer `uint8_t` will not help getting `y=0b001111`.

Comment: It would be less unexpected if you considered how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works.

Comment: A **signed** integer has a representation that doesn't use the bits the way you expect. For example take a look at [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: It inverts *all* the bits including the leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

`make y=0b001111` - no, it should not make such `y`, because `x` is `0b00000000000000000000000000110000`. `uint8_t x` will be `0b00110000` and also will not make `make y=0b001111` but `0b11001111`.

You might want to leave only 6 least bits in the result:

```
int y = ~x & 0x3F;
```

Answer (score 2):

> The thing I don't understand is why `y=-49`

The value of `y` is displayed as `-49` as the `printf` statement is printing the value of `y` as a signed integer - `%d`.
Alternatively, you could choose to print the value of `y` as an unsigned integer using `printf("y: %u\n", y)`.
This result would be-
`x = 48`
`y = 4294967247`

> because I used the bitwise NOT operator, shouldn't it reverse the bits and make y=0b001111 (y=15)?

Assuming that the size of an integer on your system is 32 bits, when the bitwise NOT operation is performed, the value stored at `y` is:
`11111111111111111111111111001111` in binary.
(Which is the same as `-49` in Signed 2's complement or `4294967247` in decimal or `0XFFFFFFCF` in hexadecimal.)

In order for you to get the desired result, you might have to use the bitwise `&` operator to mask off the undesired set of bits.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int x = 48;
    int y = ~x;
    int mask = 0xff;  //All 8 bits set to 1

    y = y & mask;
    printf("x: %d", x);
    printf("\ny: %d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The procedure for the NOT operator is to convert all ones (1's) to zeros (0's) and all zeros (0's) to ones (1's). If the sign flag is set then the number will be regarded as negative (-ve), else it will be regarded as positive (+ve).

In your example, both of your variables are 32-bit integers. So bits 6 to 31 (starting at 0 from the right bit) will be converted to ones (1's). That is why the result is -49.

As for the sign flag, it was set because an addition was done somewhere during the complement.